# How to convert boost python list to PyObject

Tags: c++, python, numpy, boost-python, python-c-api

I need to build a numpy array into C++ program

```
bp::list py_points;
// some code ....
```

and in some part of the code I need to convert **py_points** to a PyObject * type to evaluate a python module

```
PyObject * point_array, * numpy, * ndarray;
numpy = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("numpy");
ndarray = PyObject_GetAttrString(numpy, "array");
point_array = PyEval_CallObject(ndarray,bp::extract<PyObject *>(py_points)); //error!
```

the error is in this part

```
bp::extract<PyObject *>(py_points)
```

what is the correct way to convert boost python object to PyObject?

thaks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not extract a PyObject from boost::python::object. The object class has a member ptr() which is returning the underlaying PyObject.